# TFS task "Run Code Analysis" displays ERROR: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

This error started appearing in the build task "Run Code Analysis" for a web project build. I have performed the command `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`, but it did not resolve the issue.

The "Run Code Analysis" appears to complete. Any suggestions on how I can get rid of the message concerning "caniuse-lite is outdated"?

```
##[error]ERROR: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
ERROR: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
##[error]ERROR: npx browserslist@latest --update-db
ERROR: npx browserslist@latest --update-db
ERROR: 
ERROR: Why you should do it regularly:
ERROR: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how I can fix that with a good approach, but for now I suppressed this warning by adding the variable to AzureDevops
`BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA=true`.

```yaml
variables:
  ...
  - name: 'BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA'
    value: true
  ...
```

Comment: the solution worked. I added the variable BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA to the tfs task and set the value to 1. Thank you all for the solution, Joe

Comment: @J.Cortese do not forget to vote, please :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the CSS and JS analyzers of SonarQube. [It has already been fixed.](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/2803) The [CSS analyzer](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-css) has been merged into the JS analyzer since then.

[The fix](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/commit/57d320e18fc079b1a2f3684684c4b01d830fad11) has been released as part of [SonarJS 8.9.0.17411](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/releases/tag/8.9.0.17411), which was released as part of SonarQube 9.4.

As a workaround, you can set the environment variable `BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA` to `true`. This is what the analyzer fix does, anyway, just very locally. The easiest way to set an environment variable is to create a pipeline variable of the same name. Just keep in mind that if you use NPM package browserlist in your own code, the warning will be suppressed there too.